# Can't install rake-cors in rails-api app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, rails-api

I'm pretty new to rails development, so I guess it is pretty easy issue, but I still can't find a solution for it.
So I made an rails app, which works fine, except of CORS, I can't install rake-cors properly.
I've added `'gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'` to Gemfile, but after **bundle-install** I can't find `cors.rb` in `config/initializers`.

Did anyone crash into this, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `rack-cors` would create a initializer. If you followed the README on [Github](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), you have to do it yourself. Put this snippet of code into your `application.rb` file.

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

There is not an initializer in the [example](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/tree/master/examples/rails4/config/initializers.) app as well.

Comment: thanks, that's it, in my tutorial there wasn't any info about creating classes by myself, so I decided that I'm doing smthing wrong, your solution works just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add gemfile `gem 'rack-cors'`

Run `bundle install`

Add cors.rb file into `config/initialize/cors.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Don't forget to restart your rails server

For more detail settings please read: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack-cors/0.2.9